# nextAll() returns undefined - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making organizatoinal-chart-like structure. All divs have unique ID and a class that matches the ID of their parent (if they have one) like so:

```
<div id="title1" class="container"></div>
<div id="title4" class="container child title3"></div>
<div id="title3" class="container child title2"></div>
<div id="title2" class="container child title1"></div>
```

Idea is to order these in chart by absolutely positioning divs below their parent div, so they will be rendered in the right order.

Problem with the code below is that the `$test_str` returns as undefined, even if I pass `.child` as selector... and I am stuck.

```
$containers = $('.container');
$test = [];
for ( i = 0; i < $containers.length; i++ ) {
    $test_str = $($containers[i]).nextAll('.' + $containers[i].id);
    $test.push($test_str);
    console.log($containers[i].id + ' is parent ' + $test[i].id);
    //$test[i].id is returned as undefined;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YfL9L/1/)

Comment: Where have you used `findAll()`.

Comment: ahhh my mistake, i ll edit the tile right away...

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9KNqK/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take an approach of just moving the divs using `appendTo` or `insertAfter` instead of trying to absolutely position them (which I think would be more difficult). This example uses `appendTo` since it creates an actual parent-child structure instead simply re-ordering.

```
$.each($('.container'), function(ind, val) {
    $.each($('.' + val.id), function(i,v) {
       console.log(val.id + ' is parent ' + v.id);
       $(v).appendTo(val);
    }); 
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YfL9L/19/)

Comment: my friend you saved me!

Answer (score 0):

If you output the $test_str to the console, the element info is under context, so you'll want to get the id from `$test[i].context.id`

```
$containers = $('.container');
$test = [];
for ( i = 0; i < $containers.length; i++ ) {
    jQuery.fn.init();
    $test_str = $($containers[i]).nextAll('.' + $containers[i].id);
    $test.push($test_str);
    console.log($containers[i].id + ' is parent ' + $test[i].context.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that `nextAll()` returns a sequence of items and you are treating it as a single item.  The second problem you are probably going to run into is you are using nextAll() instead of siblings().

[siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

> Description: Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

[nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) returns only successors at the same level and not true siblings.

> Description: Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Here is the code showing a way to get the result you want. I took out the intermediate array for the time being as it would just further complicate this.

```
$containers = $('.container');

$test = [];
for ( i = 0; i < $containers.length; i++ ) {
    $test_str = $($containers[i]).siblings('.' + $containers[i].id);
    console.log($test_str);

    for(j = 0; j < $test_str.length; j++){
        console.log($containers[i].id + ' is parent ' + $test_str[j].id);
    }
}
```

Remember when dealing with JQuery that most of the time the functions will return a sequence of items instead of a single item, even if there is only one match.